Warning: Prop `lang` did not match. Server: "en" Client: "en-US"
I am getting warning in Next.js 14 app router.
Warning: Prop lang did not match. Server: "en" Client: "en-US"
Here is my code /app/(site)/layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
      <body className={font.className}>
        <link rel="icon" href="/images/logo.png" sizes="any" />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Dashboard>{children}</Dashboard>
          </Suspense>
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}


I'm getting this problem today when using i18next.
